# How to say if Eigenvectors of A are orthogonal or not? without computing eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

I am give  matrix :
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1 & 2 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

1. Without finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, determine whether the eigenvectors are orthogonal or not. Justify your answer

2. Express matrix $A$ in the form $A=UDU^T$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and  $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. What are $U$ and $D$ ?

I can check if a vectors are orthogonal or not, by dot product = 0

I know that if $B^T=B^{-1}$ so that $B$ be can be said orthogonal, and $B^TB=I$

I also can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but the question asks without finding them..

How to check whether eigenvalues are orthogonal or not without finding?
and how to express $A=UDU^T$?

Comment: Do you know the Spectral theorem?

Comment: The matrix is symmetric.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are not distinct then some of the eigenvectors are not orthogonal. However, there is an orthogonal basis for the vector space.

Comment: Spectral theorem is like $D$ diagonal matrix is just the main diagonal elements are $\lambda$s ? @Huy If so how i can find the orthogonal matrix $U$?

Comment: @Andy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices

Comment: @Huy yea that one says if $A$ is symmetric then $A$ can be expressed as $UDU^T$. But not saying how to find those. Cant you just give me an example or something understandable for newbey like me?

Comment: @Andy Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix? Then do it. When you find a basis of eigenvectors, simply apply G.S. to it and you'll get your $U$.

Comment: @GitGud thanks it seems that was the answer i have searched. I know what is diagonal matrix but didn't know about diagonalization of a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector correspond to $\lambda$ and let $w$ be an eigenvector correspond to $\delta$. Then
$$\lambda \langle v,w \rangle= \langle \lambda v,w \rangle=\langle Av,w \rangle=\langle v,A^tw \rangle=\langle v,\delta w \rangle=
\delta \langle v,w \rangle\Rightarrow (\lambda-\delta)\langle v,w \rangle
\Rightarrow \langle v,w \rangle=0$$